# Study thoroughly

Tags: word-order

Is the following sentence correct?

> The teacher asked the students to study thoroughly this book.

I think the following sentence will be more correct

> The teacher asked the students to thoroughly study this book.

Am I right or are both of the above sentences correct and same?

Answer (score 2):

There is an older rule in English that forbids "splitting infinitives", i.e., putting any words between "to" and the verb word. The phrase "to thouroughly study" violates this rule.

However, this is extremely common usage, and some people will argue that it is necessary to split infinitives in some cases. I have not found such a case myself, and adhere to the rule. But you will find such usage very common these days.

I agree that your first construction is awkward; I agree with another respondent that "to study this book thoroughly" is the best of the three.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above two versions are both correct.

But I think this version is more common.

> The teacher asked the students to study this book thoroughly.